# Is "nb_steps_warmup" set for each episode or globally?

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, keras-rl

When I configure a DQN agent, `nb_steps_warmup` can be set. Is this parameter set for each episode or once globally?

What I am trying to ask is, imaging I have a game environment which takes about 3000 `max. steps per episode`. The DQN is fitted as follows:

```
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=30000, visualize=True, verbose=2)
```

So, as I understand it, the fitting will run approximately 10 episodes (`nb_steps / max. steps per episode`).

If I set `nb_steps_warmup = 5000`, what actually happens?

A) `nb_steps_warmup=5000`, so 5000 out of `nb_steps=30000` are used for warming up

B) within each episode the first `nb_steps_warmup=5000` steps are used for warm up. As `nb_steps_warmup` > `max. steps per episode`, the complete episode is used for warming up, which essentially means the fitting never leaves the warming up phase.

C) sth. else?